# regular expression for non consecutive characters

Tags: regex

If a language consists of set {*a*, *b*, *c*} only how can we construct a regular expression for the langage in which no two consecutive characters appear.

eg: *abcbcabc* will be valid and *aabbcc* will rejected by the regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

This regular expression matches *abcbcabc* but not *aabbcc*

```
// (?:(\w)(?!\1))+
// 
// Match the regular expression below «(?:(\w)(?!\1))+»
//    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//    Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w)»
//       Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) «\w»
//    Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!\1)»
//       Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
```

---

**Edit**

as has been explained in the comments, string boundaries **do** matter. The regex then becomes

```
\m(?:(\w)(?!\1))+\M
```

Kudos to Gumbo.

Comment: Don’t forget the string boundaries.

Comment: @Gumbo, +1 for reminding me but I doubt it would be necessary. What would get passed to the check is the set, never an entire block of text.

Comment: If you don’t mark the start an end of the string, `abb` would also be matched.

Answer (score 2):

Can't we just keep it simple? Just 'if not' this regex:

```
/(aa|bb|cc)/
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "`()`" is a grouping notation, and "`a|b`" stands for `a` *logical-or* `b`, then, in pseudocode

```
if regexp('/(aa)|(bb)|(cc)/', string) == MATCH_FOUND
  fail;
else
  succeed;
```

Probably doesn't need the grouping, as [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) said. I have them there just to be safe and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You must match the input against something like this (coded in whatever you want), and if you found a coincidence then it is the language you want:

```
[^{aa}|{bb}|{cc}]
```